# Is it possible to validate this claim about gun shootings and SSRIs?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance

We have received an interesting question on Skeptics.SE:

[Is there a correlation between mass-murder and use of psychoactive prescription drugs such as SSRIs?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/28153/is-there-a-correlation-between-mass-murder-and-use-of-psychoactive-prescription)

My suspicion is that this is not currently answerable because there have been too few mass-murders in the last 20 years to achieve any statistical certainty about this.

However, I'd like some help validating this suspicion (or refuting it!) or at least understand how to go about it.

Can you help?

Comment: If the assertion that for all mass shootings over the last 20 years the perpetrators were taking SSRIs or similar drugs is true, & if in some appropriately defined comparison group only a small proportion take them, then it doesn't seem implausible that the sample sizes would be large enough to show a significant correlation at conventional levels. For example, if 10 out of 10 perpetrators of mass shootings were taking SSRIS, but only 10 out of 100 non-perpetrators were, you've convincing evidence of a correlation. But not, of course, of causation, & ...

Comment: it's difficult to imagine finding a comparison group similar enough to perpetrators in relevant ways to cast much doubt on the explanation that the perpetrators are just more likely to have been prescribed SSRIs in the first place.

Comment: This question *is* answerable at many levels. The best use of statistical thinking here, IMHO, is to reveal how useless statistical analysis is in addressing the underlying question of *causality*. This becomes apparent when we contemplate similar questions. For instance, if mass murder rates (by any measure) have exhibited growth in the last 20 years, it should be easy to exhibit a correlation between mass murder rates and economic growth in China, cellphone use, Justin Bieber's shoe size, or anything else also growing during the same period.